# How to create a list with 'pinned' items

Tags: javascript, css

I need a special kind of templated list.
Its not a 'listbox' - more like a list in facebook, it just keeps expanding vertically as items are added.
The magic piece of the puzzle is - any item in the list can be 'pinned'. Once pinned, no matter how many new items are added to the top of the list - or where the user moves the vertical page scrollbar to, the pinned item will never scroll off the bottom of the screen (but it can disappear off the top).

This could be likened to Excels "Freeze top row" but it could be applied to any row, they stack at the bottom of the list instead of the top, and the freeze/float doesnt take effect until the item is about to scroll off the screen...

How would one go about writing CSS/javascript for a list of items (probably divs) where any given item could 'float' above other items in such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an item is "pinned," you probably want to move it into a separate `div` for pinned items with `position: fixed` at the bottom of the viewport.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SG5M3/2/